# How do I consume a private Nuget package?

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, tfs-2015, nuget-package-restore

I have two Visual Studio solutions that get built using separate TFS 2015 builds. The first build produces a NuGet package to a network share. This part works fine.

The bit I'm struggling with is getting the second build to consume the NuGet package.

I've added a NuGet.config file to my project with the following entry.

```
<packageSources>
  <add key="My Package Sources" value="\\network\share\nuget" />
</packageSources>
```

I've added a Nuget Installer build step to the build to consume the package at this location.

[image]

Unfortunately the Nuget package isn't being installed into the project. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the NuGet arguments field for your task add the following:

```
-Source \\network\share\nuget
```

This will instruct the command line where to locate the sources from. I've no experience in setting package sources via nuget.config, so I can't answer why your's isn't working, I always use the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#options-11) switch.

Answer (score 1):

A secondary option, setup an internal NuGet Server (its free to do) and then just provide the Private NuGet Server URL in your nuget.config (along with the public nuget.org one) so that TFS can pull from either of them.  This is what we have done in our company and it works beautifully.